# Extjs5 - UI Client side GRID pagination

Tags: pagination, grid, extjs5

I am using ExtJs5 with Grails 2.4.4. I want a client side pagination on Extjs grid without calling server side. I went through a lot of forums looking for inputs on client side pagination but everywhere I see memory proxy to be used. I am using Ajax proxy call to grails controller and loading the store. Could you please help me in resolving this and provide pointers to have client side pagination working? 
Please find below my code. I am completely new to extjs. So please apologize if there is some basic error.
View :

```
Ext.define('MVC.GridPanel', {
alias: 'app.gridPanelAlias',
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype  : 'BookView',

title : Books,

store : 'Book',

multiSelect: true,

requires: ['Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn'],

columns: [
        {text: "Select", dataIndex: 'Selected', xtype: 'checkcolumn', width:25},
        {text: "Book Number", width: 55, dataIndex: bookNumber, sortable: true},
        {text: "Received", width: 50, dataIndex: 'receivedDate', sortable: true, renderer: render_date},
],      
dockedItems:
[
    { xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: 'No data to display',
        store: 'Book',
        displayInfo: true
    }
],
forceFit: true,
height:210,
split: true,
region: 'north'
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('MVC.store.Book', {
extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',

requires : [
    'MVC.model.Book'
],
config: {
storeId : 'Book',
model   : 'MVC.model.Book',
pageSize : 5,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/Book/getBooks',
    actionMethods :{
        read   : 'POST'
        },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'books',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
}  
}

});
```

Model :

```
Ext.define('MVC.model.Book', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',    
fields: [
    { name: 'Selected', type: 'bool' },
    { name: 'BookNumber', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'Received', type: 'date'}
]
});
```

Store is invoked on click of an option in accordion panel.

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Book');
store.load({
params: {
   start: 0,
   limit: 5
}
});
```

JSON response from server for the above ajax call -

> {"total":40,"success":true,"bookOrders":[{"bookNumber":"11111","receivedDate":null},{"bookNumber":"222222","receivedDate":null}]}

Answer (score 0):

In your proxy you have 'rootProperty' set to 'books', but in the server response there is 'booksOrders' property. They should be same, so either change 'rootProperty' value or the name of that property in the server response.

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/Book/getBooks',
    actionMethods :{
        read   : 'POST'
        },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'bookOrders', // here
        totalProperty: 'total'
    }
}
```

---

```
{
"total": 40,
"success": true,
"bookOrders": [{
    "bookNumber": "11111",
    "receivedDate": null
}, {
    "bookNumber": "222222",
    "receivedDate": null
}]
}
```

The same in your model definition. All your fields should be same as in response with same case.

```
Ext.define('MVC.model.Book', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',    
    fields: [
        { name: 'Selected', type: 'bool' }, // nu such field in your response
        { name: 'bookNumber', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'receivedDate', type: 'date'}
    ]
});
```

Also it is not necessary to add any params when calling store's load method. This should be enough.

```
store.load();
```

**UPDATE**

If you have control over the backend then you should write a logic to return selected page. If not try to add another chained store (`PagedBook`):

```
Ext.define('MVC.store.PagedBook', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.ChainedStore',
    requires: [
        'MVC.store.Book' // ***
    ],
    storeId: 'PagedBook',
    model: 'MVC.model.Book',
    pageSize: 5,

    source: 'Book', // ***
    loadPage: function(page) { // DIDN'T TEST IT WELL, MAY WORK INCORRECT ***
        var i = 0,
            pageSize = this.getPageSize();

        this.clearFilter();
        this.filterBy(function(rec) {
            var result = i >= (page - 1) * pageSize && i < page * pageSize;
            i = i + 1;
            return result;
        });
    }

});
```

And then use it in the grid and the paging toolbar:

```
Ext.define('MVC.GridPanel', {
    alias: 'app.gridPanelAlias',
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'BookView',

    title: Books,

    store: 'PagedBook',                 // ***

    multiSelect: true,

    requires: ['Ext.grid.column.CheckColumn'],

    // ...
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: 'No data to display',
        store: 'PagedBook',             // ***
        displayInfo: true
    }],
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Hi Alexey, I have made the above changes but still all the records from the store are loading. I want the store to have all the records but display only the specified rows per the page size. Is client side pagination possible in Ext.grid.Panel?